# Query is slow when use WHERE OR on tables left join?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join, query-optimization

I have table `user` relation OneToMany to table `A` and table `B`. I need to find users that have its partners = 275 on both table `A` and table `B`

My query is :

```
SELECT     u.id 
 FROM      user u 
 LEFT JOIN A a 
 ON        a.user_id = u.id
 LEFT JOIN B b 
 ON        b.user_id = u.id
 WHERE     a.partner_id = 275 
 OR        b.partner_id = 275
 GROUP BY  u.id 
 ORDER BY  u.id DESC 
 LIMIT     20
```

The query is slow although I create index on tables.
Here is explain:

```
id : 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: u
type: index
possible_keys: NULL
key: PRIMARY
key_len: 4
ref: NULL
rows: 20
Extra: Using index
```

I tried to remove a "OR" side like :

```
SELECT u.id FROM user u 
LEFT JOIN A a ON a.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN B b ON b.user_id = u.id
WHERE a.partner_id = 275
GROUP BY u.id ORDER BY u.id DESC LIMIT 20
```

or

```
SELECT u.id FROM user u 
LEFT JOIN A a ON a.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN B b ON b.user_id = u.id
WHERE b.partner_id = 275
GROUP BY u.id ORDER BY u.id DESC LIMIT 20
```

Both 2 queries is fast. I don't know why ?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Terminology issue -- You say "both", yet the query says "OR".  Which is it; it makes a big difference in query formulation and optimization.

Answer (score 1):

I you want user ids where either `a` or `b` has a partner of 275, you can use:

```
SELECT a.user_id
FROM A a
WHERE a.partner_id = 275
UNION 
SELECT b.user_id
FROM B b
WHERE b.partner_id = 275;
ORDER BY user_id DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Then for this query, you want indexes on `A(partner_id, user_id)` and `B(partner_id, user_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, the `OR` condition is killing the performance; that's an often-met problem in SQL.

You could try and express this with two `exists`  conditions; this avoids outer aggregation, and makes the intent clearer:

```
select u.id
from user u
where exists (select 1 from a where a.user_id = u.id and a.partner_id = 275)
   or exists (select 1 from b where b.user_id = u.id and b.partner_id = 275)
order by u.id desc limit 20
```

This brings users that have a match in `a` or `b` for the given `partner_id`.

For performance, you want the following indexes:

```
a(partner_id, user_id)
b(partner_id, user_id)
```

You can try and change the order of the columns in each index to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you have indexes on the two tables (e.g., on partner_id) an easy way to use them is to change the OR to a `UNION` or `UNION ALL`. For example

```
SELECT     u.id 
  FROM     user u 
  WHERE    u.id IN
           (SELECT a.user_id
             FROM A a
             WHERE a.partner_id = 275
           UNION
           SELECT b.user_id
             FROM B b
             WHERE b.partner_id = 275
           )
 ORDER BY  u.id DESC 
 LIMIT     20;
```

I've used an `IN` here for readability, but you could use `LEFT JOIN`, or even an `EXISTS` if you like.

The advantage of the above is that each of the SELECTs can specifically hit the indexes - and not confusing the query plan generation with an 'or'.

Note that technically you also don't need the `user` table here (e.g., you can just use the UNIONed statement and sort the user_ids from there - but I'm guessing you may also want other information from the user table.

Answer (score 0):

Where the `WHERE` conditions reference column(s) from the LEFT side of the JOIN, the join is converted to an `INNER JOIN`.  So the `LEFT JOIN`'s are not needed.  Because you need to locate rows which have "partners = 275 on both table..." The `OR` condition is not needed.  Something like this.

```
select distinct u.id 
from [user] u 
     join a a on a.user_id = u.id
     join b b on b.user_id = u.id
where a.partner_id = 275 
      and b.partner_id = 275
order by u.id desc 
limit 20;
```

Presumably, there's an index on user.id.  The a and b tables would benefit from indexes covering (user_id, partner_id)

Comment: I believe the OP wants to find the user_ids that exist (with partner 275) in *at least one* of the tables a or b. The user_ids don't need to exist in both so these inner joins are too restrictive.

Comment: Well throw another shrimp on the barby and call me Crocodile Dundee!  Would ya look at that.